# pread for very large files

Tags: c, unix, file-io, posix

I am reading a large file using `pread` as follows:

```
ssize_t s = pread(fd, buff, count, offset);
if (s != (ssize_t) count)
  fprintf(stderr, "s = %ld != count = %ld\n", s, count);
assert(s == (ssize_t ) count);
```

The above code has been working fine for small files (upto 1.5GB). However, for large file sizes, the returned number of bytes is different than the expected count.

In particular, for 2.4GB file size, my `count` is set to 2520133890 and the assertion fails with the `fprintf` saying:

`s = 2147479552 != count = 2520133890`

What makes this puzzling is that I am working on a 64-bit system and hence, `sizeof(ssize_t) = 8`.

What is the cause of this failure and how do I resolve this so that I can read the whole file in one go?

Comment: What about "offset"? Are you sure it contains zero?

Comment: What type of `count` and `offset`? Do you use right version of `pread` from `libc`, for example on Linux there are `pread` and `pread64`, and you have to be sure that you use `pread64` function from `glibc`?

Comment: @GiuseppeGuerrini  offset is always set to 0.

Comment: @user1034749 I tried explicitly using pread64 and the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Then you need to print sizeof(off_t), sizeof(size_t), sizeof(ssize_t) to make sure that they equal to 8

Comment: @user1034749 
`fprintf(stderr, "sizeof(off_t) = %lu, sizeof(size_t) = %lu, sizeof(ssize_t) = %lu\n", sizeof(off_t), sizeof(size_t), sizeof(ssize_t));`


sizeof(off_t) = 8, sizeof(size_t) = 8, sizeof(ssize_t) = 8.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you use linux, and magic number return by `pread` is 2147479552 = 0x7ffff000, so the answer is in `man 2 read`:

> On Linux, read() (and similar  system  calls)  will  transfer  at 
>   most 0x7ffff000  (2,147,479,552)  bytes, returning the number of bytes
>   actu‐ ally transferred.  (This is true on both 32-bit and 64-bit
>   systems.)

So you need at least twice to call `pread` to get your data,
this restriction not related to `_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64`, `O_LARGEFILE`, `sizeof(off_t)` and etc things,
this restriction is create by `rw_verify_area` in linux kernel:

```
/*
 * rw_verify_area doesn't like huge counts. We limit
 * them to something that fits in "int" so that others
 * won't have to do range checks all the time.
 */
int rw_verify_area(int read_write, struct file *file, const loff_t *ppos, size_t count)
...
return count > MAX_RW_COUNT ? MAX_RW_COUNT : count;
```

`#define MAX_RW_COUNT (INT_MAX & PAGE_CACHE_MASK)`

Comment: Wow, learn something new every day. FWIW, on my system the read(2) man page does not contain this text, e.g. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html does.

Comment: The fix in man page was introduced ~ Feb, 2016, recent enough to spread across linux distributives (https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=630029)

Comment: Short reads can happen anyway. Plus, I/O subsystem would split the large requests. Typical recommendations I have heard recently were max 8-16MB per I/O.

Comment: It is interesting how various implementation decisions prop-up when testing is performed at scale. @user1034749: is there a design/logical reason why such a generalized check was implemented (and not specialized based on 32-bit/64-bit platforms)?

Comment: These lines of code wrote somebody called Linus Torvalds, and that how he  explains them: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.kernel.commits.head/67962

Answer (score 1):

From your description it sounds like you're doing a 32-bit build, and you haven't enabled the Large File Support (LFS). In order to do this, you need to set the macro _FILE_OFFSET_BITS to the value 64.

So, please double-check that you're really doing a 64-bit build like you say.. EDIT: Ok I believe you are indeed using a 64-bit system.

I think the correct cause of your problem, as pointed out in the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/36568630/75652 , is explained in the read(2) man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html . In order to handle this, you need code like

```
  bytes_left = count;
  while (bytes_left > 0)
    {
      trans = pread (fd, buff, bytes_left, offset);
      if (trans == -1)
        {
          if (errno == EINTR)
            continue;
          else
            return trans;
        }
      buff += trans;
      bytes_left -= trans;
      offset += trans;
    }

  return count - bytes_left;
```

Comment: Upon running `ldd`, it looks like a 64-bit build:

`$ ldd program
 linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4e18f000)
 libboost_system.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_system.so.1.54.0 (0x00007fe57440b000)
 libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libboost_filesystem.so.1.54.0 (0x00007fe5741f5000)
 libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fe573ef0000)
 libgomp.so.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1 (0x00007fe573ce1000)`

Comment: `libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fe573acb000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe5738ac000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe5734e7000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe5731e1000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005562e9fca000)`